# How to edit/delete datatables server side using python (flask/mysql)?

Tags: mysql, ajax, flask, datatables, server-side

Flask

@app.route("/ajaxfiletest",methods=["POST","GET"])
def ajaxfiletest():
try:
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
if request.method == 'POST':
draw = request.form['draw']
row = int(request.form['start'])
rowperpage = int(request.form['length'])
searchValue = request.form["search[value]"]
print(draw)
print(row)
print(rowperpage)
print(searchValue)

```
        ## Total number of records without filtering
        cursor.execute("select count(*) as allcount from ates")
        rsallcount = cursor.fetchone()
        totalRecords = rsallcount['allcount']
        print(totalRecords) 

        ## Total number of records with filtering
        likeString = "%" + searchValue +"%"
        cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) as allcount from ates WHERE tes1 LIKE %s OR tes2 LIKE %s ", (likeString, likeString))
        rsallcount = cursor.fetchone()
        totalRecordwithFilter = rsallcount['allcount']
        print(totalRecordwithFilter) 

        ## Fetch records
        if searchValue=='':
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ates ORDER BY id_ates asc limit %s, %s;", (row, rowperpage))
            testing = cursor.fetchall()
        else:        
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ates WHERE tes1 LIKE %s OR tes2 LIKE %s limit %s, %s;", (likeString, likeString, row, rowperpage))
            testing = cursor.fetchall()

        data = []
        for row in testing:
            data.append({
                'id_ates': row['id_ates'],
                'tes1': row['tes1'],
                'tes2': row['tes2'],
                'tes3': row['tes3'],
            })

        response = {
            'draw': draw,
            'iTotalRecords': totalRecords,
            'iTotalDisplayRecords': totalRecordwithFilter,
            'aaData': data,
        }
        return jsonify(response)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatables').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{ url_for('ajaxfiletest') }}",
            "type": 'POST'
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id_ates"},
            {"data": "tes1"},
            {"data": "tes2"},
            {"data": "tes3"},
        ]
    });

} );
</script>
```

```html
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row" style="padding:50px;">
        <p><h1>test edit delete server side</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding:50px;">
        <div >
            <table id='datatables' class='display' width='100%'>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>tes1</th>
                    <th>tes2</th>
                    <th>tes3</th>
                    <th>Edit | Delete</th>
                </tr>
                </thead> 
            </table>
        </div>
   </div>
   
</div>
```

How to edit/delete datatables server side using python (flask/mysql)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how to add edit and delete button in datatables server side?

Answer (score 1):

Im able to delete table record using script below, only if i put number in id_ates, for example id_ates=5, but if i write id_ates=id, its not working...

(Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ())

```js
// Delete Record from Database.
    var table= $("#datatables").DataTable();
    $("#datatables").on('click',  '[id*=btnDelete]', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id_ates");
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
        $.ajax({
            "url": "{{url_for('delfiletest', id_ates=5)}}",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id_ates:id},
            success:function(data) {                    
                table.ajax.reload();
            }
        })
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```